# Semi(Auto) Code Generating with Python/Java/etc

Tags: javascript, python, code-generation

Before anyone down votes or call out as duplicate. I searched for code generation, auto code complete, code complete with python, and code automation with `Java/Python` and every results I have got were not relevant to task I want to achieve.

I am free to use any language but Java or Python are preferred due to various libraries and api support.

Task I have is: need to write a program that outputs `*.js` file  and in that file I am going to have a same function printed many time as number of inputs.

Here Only thing that changes is name of the function and to speak.

n These two inputs are passed in as CSV file like column one is **NAME**  and Column two is **MESSAGE(to speak)**
---------------------------------- output.js -------------------------------

```
module.exports = {
john: john,
tony: tony,
laura: laura
};


function john(assistant) {
let toSpeak = "Here something goes for John";
assistant.setContext("navigator", 1, {"mynavigator": OPTIONS});
return askAssistant(toSpeak, assistant);

function tony(assistant) {
let toSpeak = "whatever is message for tony";
assistant.setContext("navigator", 1, {"mynavigator": OPTIONS});
return askAssistant(toSpeak, assistant);

function laura(assistant) {
let toSpeak = "I think you got where I am going with";
assistant.setContext("navigator", 1, {"mynavigator": OPTIONS});
return askAssistant(toSpeak, assistant)
```

`-----------------------------output.js------------------------------------------`

I am not asking anyone to code this for me rather suggest me a tool that would help me achieve this task. I will sincerely appreciate your kind feedback

Comment: *I am not asking anyone to code this for me rather suggest me a tool that would help me achieve this task.* - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I already described the problem. Before you downvote take time time read. I am not outputting simple print statement here. I searched for api or something that would help me achieve task I am doing.  "opinionated answers and spam" may have something that I am looking for. THANKS

Comment: I only copy pasted Stackoverflow's Default Text into the comment. No matter how much I agree with you and how much spam or opinionated answer help you Stackoverflow doesn't  like it. Don't shoot the messenger. Feel free to check out the links SO provides on that topic -
 What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) or

Comment: I thank you for your feedback. There was no need for downvote(Whoever did it). what do you suggest? I could not find on google hence I posted here.

Comment: I think in general SO likes for us to [**do our own research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144) and decide on the tools ourselves and if we have issues with the implementation to post the code in question in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you to fix the issue. I can;t suggest anything myself, I suppose I'd be just googling myself silly and ask on other sites until I find a library or tool that would do what I need :(

Comment: a specific programming problem [check]
    a software algorithm[check]
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is [check]
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development[check]  If one does not know where to even start then obviously they would not have code to share.

Comment: I think by *software tools commonly used by programmers* it's in the context of asking questions where you have issues with code **using** such tools , not asking for which tools to use.

Comment: A common problem with "using such tools" is to choose a good one to use.  I happen to think the SO rules here are nonsense but that's a long ago battle.  If you insist on quoting the party line (you'd didn't have to, esp. if you didn't agree with it), you might at least have pointed OP to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where such questions are welcome.  (Isn't it peculiar that standard Default Text doesn't do this?)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches you could take.

The first approach is to use `print` statements in your favourite programming language to print out the required text. And, of course, wrap some of those `print` statements in `for`-loops to iterate over the list of (name, message) tuples. This approach is straightforward and does not require use of any third-party code-generation tools.

The second approach is to use a template engine, such as [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) (for Java).